# How to melt dataframe columns into rows?

Tags: python, pandas

I have checked a lot of `melt` related questions here but none of them work for what I want to do.

I have this dataframe:

[image]

And I want to melt it to this shape:

[image]

I have tried a lot of different variations of melt & pivot from stack overflow.

If this is a duplicate question let me know because I wasn't able to find a solution.

My test dataframe:

```
stack.to_dict()

{'A': {0: 1, 1: 5}, 'B': {0: 2, 1: 6}, 'C': {0: 3, 1: 7}, 'D': {0: 4, 1: 8}}
```

Comment: ```melt``` does exactly what you need. For a dataframe ```df``` try ```df.melt()```

Comment: @porrrwal Oh wow! That works.  I was adding all kinds of arguments to the `melt()` function, that I didn't need to! That's why I was messing it up. I added `id_vars=df.columns` like other stack overflow answers,  which seemed to break it.

Comment: Use `df.melt(value_name='Number', var_name='Letter')`